# Class atributes not updating [node.js - express ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, neo4j

I have some troubles with a .js Object's atribute which is not updating when i ask it to.

I'm new in the javascript world, so i hope my issue won't be tricky.

First of all, this is a part of my Node class :

```
Node = function (label, vals, db, callback) {
    // attributes
    this.label = label;
    this.vals = vals;
    this.db = db;
    if (typeof calback == 'function') calback();
}
Node.prototype.insert_db = function (calback) {
    var vals = this.vals;
    // Create a node 
    console.log("1:"); // output print
    console.log(vals); // output print
    this.db.save(vals, function (err, node) {
        if (err) throw err;
        vals = node;
        console.log("2:"); // output print
        console.log(vals); // output print
    });
    this.vals = vals;
    console.log("3:"); // output print
    console.log(this.vals); // output print
    if (typeof calback == 'function') calback();
}
```

what i want to do with this code, is to update the "id" value of a my Node object after insertion. But... here is my console.log after runing this code :

```
var per = new Node('Whatever', { firstName: "aaaa", lastName: "aaaa", age: "aaaa" }, db2);
per.insert_db();
```

Console output :

```
1:
{ firstName: 'aaaa', lastName: 'aaaa', age: 'aaaa' }
3:
{ firstName: 'aaaa', lastName: 'aaaa', age: 'aaaa' }
2:
{ firstName: 'aaaa', lastName: 'aaaa', age: 'aaaa', id: 491 }
```

The 3rd state is (in second position) never get updated.
I don't know where it comes from. I've spent the last 2 days on that problem, that i obviously can't handle anymore.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Still having troubles.
Thanks to @MarkHughes, here is my new code

```
Node.prototype.insert_db = function (callback) {
    var temp = this;
    this.db.save(this.vals, function (err, node) {
        if (err) throw err;
        temp.vals = node;
        console.log(temp.vals); // output print
        if (typeof callback == 'function') callback();
    });
}
```

Code ran by this one

```
var per = new Node('Person', { firstName: "aaaa", lastName: "aaaa", age: "aaaa" }, db2);
per.insert_db(res.render('login-index', { title: 'miam', dump: mf.dump(per) }));
```

Now here are the `console.log(temp.vals)`

```
{ firstName: 'aaaa', lastName: 'aaaa', age: 'aaaa', id: 515 }
```

And here is the rendered output (pre html) :

```
vals:  object(3): {
    firstName:  string(4): "aaaa"
    lastName:  string(4): "aaaa"
    age:  string(4): "aaaa"
}
```

The output is **in** the callback function wich is **in** the asynchronous function `.save`... And still no update. :(

I don't know if this helps, for debug only :

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(temp) }, 3000);
```

written after the `.save` function returns this :

```
[...]
vals: { firstName: 'aaaa', lastName: 'aaaa', age: 'aaaa', id: 517 },
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.save is asynchronous, so you can't use the value returned by it outside its callback, hence moving the rest of your code inside the callback will fix it:

```
var t = this;
this.db.save(vals, function (err, node) {
    if (err) throw err;
    vals = node;
    console.log("2:"); // output print
    console.log(vals); // output print

    t.vals = vals;
    console.log("3:"); // output print
    console.log(t.vals); // output print
    if (typeof calback == 'function') calback();
});
```

Saving "this" into a variable allows access to it from inside the callback.

For your calling code, you need to ensure you are rendering the output in the callback from insert_db() - e.g. something like:

```
per.insert_db(function () { 
    res.render('login-index', { title: 'miam', dump: mf.dump(per) })
});
```

Note that you have to wrap res.render in a function() else what will be passed in as the callback will be the return value of executing that function, rather than the function itself.

Comment: The problem here is that the `this.vals` "inside" the `this.db.save` function does not refer to my Node object, but to a different global object.

Comment: @JohnSmith OK I've updated - this is to do with the variable scoping rules in Javascript which can be a little confusing :) By saving `this` into a local variable, you can then update that from inside the callback.

Comment: @JohnSmith Note also the importance of putting the call to `calback()` **inside** this callback so it doesn't execute until after the save is complete - therefore anything which calls insert_db can have code to wait for the save to complete before executing.

Comment: Still have troubles. Thank you anyway.  :) Main issue edited.

Comment: @JohnSmith You're close - just wrap the callback in a function() { } block and I suspect you'll be there. Take a look at my latest edit.

Comment: **GIVE THAT MAN A COOKIE !!**
It works ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Welcome - don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with the solution!